# How can i generate random colors in C# with a button click?

Tags: c#, multithreading, random, concurrency

I have a program which sends planes to different destination and it's implemented using threading. But the problem is my planes don't generate in random colors on button click, it generates random colors whenever the program is run. (I think this is because i haven't passed the method properly in the button clicking method)

Question is how can i change the code so that it generates random colors whenever the button is clicked?

And my code is given below. (There are few radio buttons which will prompt the user for the destination and when the button is clicked the planes will go)

my code for the button click instance

```
    private void rbutton1_checked(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (((RadioButton)sender).Checked == true)         
            destination = 1;
    }

    private void rbutton2_checked(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (((RadioButton)sender).Checked == true)
            destination = 2;
    }

    private void rbutton3_checked(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (((RadioButton)sender).Checked == true)
            destination = 3;
    }

    private void rbutton4_checked(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (((RadioButton)sender).Checked == true)
            destination = 4;
    }

    private void btn_Click(object sender,
                           System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (destination == 0) MessageBox.Show("Select an Option Please!!");

        else
        {
            for (int q = 0; q <1000; q++)
            {
                locked = !locked;
                this.btn.BackColor = locked ? Color.Pink : Color.LightGreen;
                lock (this)
                {
                    if (!locked)
                        Monitor.Pulse(this);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And my code for the random color generation which is not in the same class ( In the Form)

```
public Color generateRandomColor()
    {

        Random random = new Random();
        Color color = Color.FromArgb(random.Next(255), random.Next(255), random.Next(255));
        return color;

    }
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you're calling your `generateRandomColor()`. but if you want it to happen on button click, why not call it from there?

Comment: sorry i couldn't mention this but i'm calling the method when i'm calling the constructor of the class which has all the bottons. 

p.s - i tried calling the method from the button click event didn't work

Comment: Why use 3 identical radio button handlers?

Answer (score 1):

Create on instance of Random class on load of your program. Then when user click on button to generate random color, it will give you different values.
The problem is that you're always creating a new instance of the Random class, and this object starts with the same seed value by default, so you have always the same "random" number.

But, pay attention that with code (in any language) you will get only a pseudo random. To get really random number you must have specific hardware to this.